# how to start the HAL service, only after specific android HAL service

Tags: hal

Could you please let me know how to start the HAL service, only after specific android HAL service is available.
Like adding requires or after is systemd service files in linux

Answer (score 0):

suppose there are 2 HALs A and B. And you want to wait for HAL B to run HAL A then you can add different class name in their own .rc files like

service A /vendor/bin/HAL_A
class hal_a

service B /vendor/bin/HAL_B
class hal_b

After the files system is mounted by "on fs" trigger you can start the HAL B by using

class_start "<\class_name>" in your case class name will be hal_b

class_start "<\class_name>" in your case class name will be hal_a

Place a while loop in hal_a before hal_a itself register with hwservicemanager and check the hal_b using getservice() method of hwservicemanager one you get the binder interface then start hal_a and add it to hwservice manager.